# javascript addEventListener by querySelector not work

Tags: javascript, debugging, addeventlistener, selectors-api

HI this is my javascript code :

```
window.onload = function () {

    function hideAds() {
        setTimeout(hide, 2000);
    }

    function hide() {
        var ads = document.querySelector(".ads");
        ads.style.marginTop = (-ads.offsetHeight) + "px";
    }

    function reveal() {
        ads.style.marginTop = "";
        hideAds();
    }
    var ads = document.querySelector(".ads");
    ads.addEventListener("click", reveal, true);


    hideAds();

}
```

from this code, everything work fine other then "ads.addEventListener" second line from last. what is the reason? is i made anything wrong here..?

i need to call my reveal function by click the ads class added div.

any one help me?

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe you want to add the listener to the parent, because the .ads is probably hidden.

Comment: @patrick Yea, Patrick. Don't you see how beautifully formatted the code is? What are you talking about? `:)`

Comment: what patrick dw say is correct. by urgent, i unable to format the code. i am sorry.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yeah, what was I thinking? ;o)

Comment: @3gwebtrain: If you're saying you don't know how, there are buttons along the top of the edit area. You just select your code and click the *Code Sample* button. It looks like **`{ }`**.

Comment: if you just want to get the work done, iterate the `var ads` and then call the function for every `ads[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you gave should work as it is. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/J67bA/)

But I'd be tempted to re-factor your code like so.

HTML

```
<div class="ads">Blah blah blah</div>
```

Javascript

```
function setMarginTop(element, marginTop) {
    element.style.marginTop = marginTop || null;
}

function hideAds(element, marginTop, ms) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        setMarginTop(element, marginTop);
    }, ms || 2000);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var ads = document.querySelector('.ads'),
        hide = (-ads.offsetHeight) + 'px';

    hideAds(ads, hide);
    ads.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        var target = evt.target;

        setMarginTop(target)
        hideAds(target, hide);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5WM2t/)

Answer (score 1):

This one is without delaying 2000ms before the ads actually appear:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ads = document.querySelector(".ads");

    function hideAds() {
        setTimeout(hide, 2000);
    }

    function hide() {
        ads.style.marginTop = (-ads.offsetHeight) + "px";
    }

    function reveal() {
        ads.style.marginTop = "";
        hideAds();
    }

    ads.addEventListener("click", reveal, true);

    hideAds();
}
```